# Создание симлинков в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, веб-программирование, artisan, symlinks

Смотрел видео [Загрузка файлов в Laravel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-iuZhHDtOW4&list=PL8jSdafHd96wsHGWVlS3_BxHS5FJ4ReND&index=24). Там с 12:20-13:40 происходит создание симлинка папки `storage\app\public` в папку `public\storage`. Это происходит с помощью команды `php artisan storage:link`. Каким образом для этой команды задается папка, симлинк которой происходит и папка, в которую помещается симлинк?

Comment: Если пролистать в документации до [The Public Disk](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk) и еще немножечко ниже, то можно наткнуться на: "You may configure additional symbolic links in your filesystems configuration file.", -- что указывает на `config/filesystems.php`.

Comment: @Simon в файле `config/filesystems.php` я нашел строку `'links' => [public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),]`.Но каким образом задается путь, в который помещается симлинк - `public\storage`?

Comment: @Simon или `public_path('storage')` и есть `public\storage`?

Comment: Ну да, само названиее функции `public_path()` намекает на то что это путь к папочку `public`.